# WebSphere MQ: Is possible to define FIFO (first in, first out) in Cluster?

Tags: websphere, cluster-computing, ibm-mq, fifo

please help me...

Is possible to define FIFO (first in, first out) in Active-Active cluster on AIX?

In two DC how is possible to manage fifo queues?

I have this scenario Active/active clustering for websphere mq.

Thank you!

[enter link description here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSRLD6_7.0.1/com.ibm.omegamon.mes.doc_7.0.1/c_pre_activeactive_AIX.html)

Comment: Is it FIFO only from the producer standpoint or for multiple producers is it also need to be FIFO across all producers?  If the former you can bind on OPEN which means all messages from that producer will go to the same instance of the remote clustered queue until the queue is closed and opened again.  To work around problems of one of the queue managers going down you can open and close the queue periodically.

Comment: Another option could be to target two different clustered queue manager aliases.  You could keep one enabled on each destination clustered qmgr, if one goes down you could enable both on the remaining.

Comment: Do you have any feedback to provide on my questions?